# polynomial division, gcd, question

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

We are asked to show that there are polynomials $p,q \in Q[t]$ such that:

$p(t)*(t^4+2t^2+1)+q(t)*(t^4-3t^2-4) = t^2+1$

Is the answer the same for $t+5$ instead of $t^2+1$?

What I tried doing:

I don't really know why, but I thought maybe finding the gcd of $(t^4+2t^2+1)$ and $(t^4-3t^2-4)$ would help, maybe its $t^2+1$, but it wasnt.

I don't have an idea how to solve this.

Comment: If we are working with polynomials over the rationals, or the reals, or the complex numbers, then $t^2+1$ **is** a gcd of your two given polynomials. There are no polynomials $p(t)$, $q(t)$ that give $t+5$.

Comment: really? I got $t^2-1$ guess I did something wrong...ok, but even if it is the gcd. Why would that help us? Why does this mean that there are such polynomials q and p?

Comment: Well, for one thing it is a general theorem. If $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ are polynomials over a field, and $d(t)$ is their gcd, then there exist polynomials $p(t),q(t)$ such that $a(t)p(t)+b(t)q(t)=d(t)$.

Comment: In your case, $\frac{1}{5}$ times the first, plus $-\frac{1}{5}$ times the second, is equal to $t^2+1$.

Comment: what about question B? If we swap $t^2+1$ for $t+5$?

Comment: Since $t^2+1$ divides each of your polynomials $a(t)$ and $b(t)$, it divides $a(t)p(t)+b(t)q(t)$ for any polynomials $p(t),q(t)$. But $t^2+1$ does not divide $t+5$. So we cannot get $t+5$ as a "linear combination" of the given polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
t^4 + 2t^2 + 1 = (t^2+1)^2, \text{ and } t^4-3t^2-4 = (t^2+1)(t^2-4)
$$
So $t^2 + 1$ is the gcd.

You are in $\mathbb{Q}[t]$, which is a Euclidean domain - in which the gcd of two elements is a "linear combination" of those two elements (You should find a proof of this in pretty much any reasonable book on ring theory). Hence, there exist polynomials $p(t), q(t)$ as you require.